# Save canvas as jpeg and inputfields to database via js

Tags: javascript, database, html, canvas

So I can upload a picture into canvas, then in canvas you should be able to customise the picture (which also doesn't work but that problem is less pressing). Then after you customise it you must give your email and name, and these 3 things should be sent to the database so I can get them in a gallery. But my code-skills are not good enough to get this right, and finding all these different methods just confuse me at the moment.

This is my form

```
<div id="canvas">
  <canvas width="800" height="700" id="canvas_manly"><img id="image"/></canvas>
  <form>
    <div class="formcontent">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="name" placeholder="Name"></br>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="input" name="email" placeholder="Email"></br>
      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" onClick="sendInfo"></br>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I have no idea how to continue from here out.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are a few notes to get you started:**

Assuming you have elements to input the user's name & email and a canvas element containing the marked up content:

```
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<div>
    <input type='text' id='name'>
    <input type='text' id='email'>
</div>
```

Then you can get references to these elements in javascript:

```
// get references to the desired elements
var nameElement=document.getElementById('name');
var emailElement=document.getElementById('email');
var canvasElement=document.getElementById('canvas');
```

You can use jQuery's AJAX method to POST the user's name & email plus the canvas content in dataURL form. You can convert the canvas content to a dataURL (a string) using the canvas's .toDataURL method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "scriptOnYourServerToSaveToDatabase.php",
  data:{
      name: nameElement.value,
      email: emailElement.value,
      image: canvasElement.toDataURL()
  }
})
  .done(function(result){
    alert("Done: "+result);
  });
```

Of course, the `scriptOnYourServerToSaveToDatabase` script will depend on what server & database software you are using.